# Is there a way to handle or split multi-part TIFF images in Google App Engine?

Tags: java, image, google-app-engine

A number of the libraries I have looked at use restricted classes - I have tried using the [built in App Engine Image processing](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/images/overview.html#Image_Formats) which can convert the first page of the file, but will ignore subsequent pages. The [wikipedia entry on TIFF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tagged_Image_File_Format#Multiple_subfiles) does say this is acceptable behavior for TIFF files as the multi-part functionality is optional.

The files are being received in the app via email, and I cannot ask the sender to use another format. Any ideas short of writing my own parser for the bytes in a TIFF?